# Bash script - check if a variable is located between 2 others variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-scripting, conditional, variables

In a Bash script I want to check if var1 is located between var2 and var3.
But I can't find how to do it.

Something like this.

```
var1=15
var2=10
var3=20

if [ "$var1" is located beetween "$var2" and "$var3" ]
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

Can you help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "located between"? Value? If so, `man test`.  If something else, please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the values are always numeric and by "var1 located between var2 and var3" you mean that `var2 < var1 < var3`, you can use this:

```
if (( $var2 < $var1 )) && (( $var1 < $var3 )); then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

Comment: thank you 

everything works with your example adapted to my script

Answer (score -2):

Your logic is pointless... After all the code in the script is static, so when you change anything in the variables, you can adjust the logic in the rest of the script.

Comment: It's probably a fair assumption that was a sample script to illustrate his question rather than his actual script.

Comment: That's an assumption and I still think that the question is poorly written.